# Center align text of unequal lengths in rows in R dataframe and fill flanking positions

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyverse

Can I center align text of all rows of a specified column of R dataframe? An example is given below:

```
Gene.names = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")
Sequence = c("AAGVEAAAEVAATEIKMEEES", "ATMKDDLADYGGYDGGYVQDYEDFM", "ATNIEQIFRSF", "GILFCGRFSSP", "SLRASTSKSESSQK")
df = data.frame(Gene.names, Sequence)
```

As can be seen, the sequences are of different lengths. I need to center align the sequences and then add any letter (e.g., X) on both sides of the shorter sequences as many as required to make all sequences of equal length.

Is this even possible in R? I am still learning R and any directions or packages etc. will be very helpful.

Thank you.

Comment: do you just want the table to *look* centred when you print it to console or device (for this something like `xtable` will work). Or do you actually need the spaces in the data?

Comment: Indeed, in those cases I am doing `df= as.data.frame(gsub("\\s", "X", format(df$Sequence, width=max(nchar(df$Sequence)))))`. Dont know if there is an elegant alternative but this works for me.

Answer (score 2):

We get the number of characters with `nchar`, find the `max` of those ('mx'), subtract that from the number of characters, divide by 2, and if the number of characters is shorter than than the `max`, then `paste` on either side with replicated 'X' (`strrep`)

```
nr <- nchar(df$Sequence)
mx <- max(nr)
i1 <- ceiling((mx -nr)/2)
out <- ifelse(i1 > 0, paste0(strrep("X", i1), df$Sequence, strrep("X", i1)),
              df$Sequence)
substr(out, 1, mx)
```

---

If this is for viewing, another option is `DT::datatable`

```
library(DT)    
datatable(df, options = list(columnDefs = list(list(className = 
                 'dt-center', targets = 2))))
```

-output in html

[image]

---

Or using `htmlTable`

```
library(htmlTable)
htmlTable(df, align = c("r", "c"))
```

-output

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much :) Only a minor problem. Does not output `characters with same length`. But I can solve it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use xtable to format the table for viewing, without actually altering the data

```
library(xtable)
library(rstudioapi)

x = xtable(df, align = c('r','r','c'))

view_x <- function(x){
  tab <- paste(capture.output(print(x, type = 'html')), collapse = '\n')
  tf <- tempfile(fileext = ".html")
  writeLines(tab, tf)
  viewer(tf)
}

view_x(x)
```

[image]